# ReNative Tizen Devices

Tags: reactjs, native, tizen

I'm trying to launch my TV app on Samsung Tizen device but after launching it successfully it's giving me the following issue.

unable to load the page 192.168.52.1:8087 maybe temporarily down or moved at a new url.
What would be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please specify better your scenario. You are talking about launch your Tizen Smart TV App (which Tizen version?) but also you are trying to open a web service in a private IP location (192.168.52.1:8087).

Review Tizen smart TV specifications due all apps must be loaded from local resources (built-in wgt package)

Best regards